# How to share a custom content with facebook sdk

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm building a real estate website and I put a share button so members can share a single estate including image on their timeline but I didn't find a way to implement it.
I used "share dialog" but I think it doesn't serve the purpose. And I read about "feed dialog" that contains some properties like "description" and "picture" but as I read these are deprecated and I have used but doesn't work.

Comment: that data comes from the open graph tags. you need to include them in your page.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters

Comment: I solved the problem. I think the problem was in ssl certificate because I was in development with vagrant homestead but when I deploy the app on real server it works!